# Past simple or past continuous is more accurate

Tags: grammar

Which is correct: I came back home at 10 p.m. yesterday or I was coming back home yesterday

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. It depends on what you're trying to say. First one can be informative and the second one can be the answer to a question about yesterday.

Comment: You would only normally use the "continuous" version in a sentence like *I was coming back home yesterday **when I met John***. That's to say, the only reason to use the continuous here is if you're using it ***to identify a time-span*** (*within* which time *somewthing else happened*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use simple past and when I should use simple past progressive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114420/when-should-i-use-simple-past-and-when-i-should-use-simple-past-progressive)

Comment: Yes, it answered my question. These sentences are confusing for foreign learners. The exercise book neglected to add something to help the learners decide the tense correctly and the teacher's book didn't accept both tenses. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

"I came back home at 10 p.m. yesterday" means that you *arrived* at 10pm.

"I was coming back home at 10 p.m. yesterday" means that you were *still traveling* back home at 10pm.

Answer (score 1):

** I came back home at 10 p.m** is correct.

The Past Continuous tense is an important tense in English. We use it to say what we were in the middle of doing at a particular moment in the past.

The Past Continuous tense expresses action at a particular moment in the past. The action started before that moment but has not finished at that moment. For example, yesterday I watched a film on TV. The film started at 7pm and finished at 9pm.

**When we use the Past Continuous tense, our listener usually knows or understands what time we are talking about. Look at these examples:**

> I was working at 10pm last night.

> They were not playing football at 9am this morning.

> What were you doing at 10pm last night?

> What were you doing when he arrived?

> She was cooking when I telephoned her.

> We were having dinner when it started to rain.

> Ram went home early because it was snowing.